# 401 (Unauthorized) ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, http-headers, authorization, fetch

I'm facing a problem here, I'm developing a Rest API and a Web App using ReactJS. I'm trying to make a `fetch` request to the Rest API, but always receive back a 401 code meaning Unauthorized access. I'm sending the `fetch request` in the following code:

```
  SubmitClick(){

    if (this.state.password !== this.state.reTypepassword){
      alert('Passwords do not match. Please check your data !');
    } else {
      //console.log(this.state); //debug only
      fetch('http://localhost:4000/users/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Basic YWRtaW46c3VwZXJzZWNyZXQ=',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email: this.state.email,
          first_name: this.state.first_name,
          last_name: this.state.last_name,
          personal_phone: this.state.personal_phone,
          password: this.state.password
        })
      }).then(this.props.history.push('/get'));  //change page layout and URL
    }
  }
```

As you can see, I'm inserting the Authorization header in the request following this structure: `('Authorization' : 'Basic ' + encoding)`. I got the encoding value in my request from Postman software.

Here is the code for my Rest API, where I configure the user and passwords allowed:

```
const express =     require('express');
const bodyParser =  require('body-parser');
const mongoose =    require('mongoose');
var basicAuth =     require('express-basic-auth')

const app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/usersregs', { useMongoClient: true });
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

app.use(basicAuth({
    users: {
        'admin': 'supersecret',
        'adam': 'password1234',
        'eve': 'asdfghjkl'
    }
}))

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
    console.log(err);
    //res.status(450).send({err: err.message})
});

app.use(require('./routes/api'));  

app.listen(4000, function(){
    console.log('Now listening for request at port 4000');
});
```

Using Google Chrome Developer Tools, I can see the request headers in this operation, [as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIXL5.png)

If I remove the part of the code which I configure the Users and Passwords (in the Rest API), and the part that which configures the Authorization header (Web App), the code works properly. I can't make it work with the Authorization header.

What am I supposed to do with Authorization header in the fetch request, so I can have access to the Rest API?

Comment: instead of `fetch` use `axios` https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: I tried that but I'm still receiving the same error

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem has to do with the `express-basic-auth` module that you are using. See this part of the [documentation](https://github.com/LionC/express-basic-auth):

> The middleware will now check incoming requests to match the credentials `admin:supersecret`.
>
> The middleware will check incoming requests for a basic auth (`Authorization`) header, **parse it** and check if the credentials are legit. If there are any credentials, an auth property will be added to the request, containing an object with user and password properties, filled with the credentials, no matter if they are legit or not.

The document doesn't mention anything about `Basic + encoding` for the Authorization header. You should try using `admin:supersecret` as the value of the Authorization header.

**Update:**

I think you are misusing the module. The `express-basic-auth` seems to be used just to make sure you are authenticated and allows you through to obtain information to the API. It has hardcoded user/password credentials in the server, which does not seem to allow for registration the way you are using. The package description says,

> Simple plug & play HTTP basic auth middleware for Express.

So it is just HTTP basic authentication. For a registration/login system, I would [recommend using passport](http://www.passportjs.org/).

Comment: I tried using `admin:supersecret` but still got the same response... `Basic + encoding` I saw in some codes here at Stack Overflow, some other examples in the internet and following the [HTTP Basic Authetication](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E39820_01/doc.11121/gateway_docs/content/authn_http_basic.html)

Comment: Could you also add `'Accept': 'application/json'` to the headers?

Comment: Please remove the empty middleware otherwise you will never get through: `app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
    console.log(err);
    //res.status(450).send({err: err.message})
});`

Comment: @rk_Tinelli already updated the answer; I think you are mis-using the module. It should not be used that way. See my suggestion.